# Collections using has_many, :through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, collections

I want the current user to read and purchase postings in clubs in which he is a member.
I would love to do something like the following, but nothing I've read or tried has clicked yet.  I will be using many nesting collections of this type, I'm stuck!
**Models**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :memberships
        has_many :clubs, :through => :memberships
        has_many :products

    class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :club

    class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :memberships
        has_many :users, :through => :memberships
        has_many :events

   class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :club

   class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        has_many :posts

   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :product
        belongs_to :event
```

**Posts Controller**

```
def index
   @user = current_user
   @posts_in_my_clubs = @user.memberships.collect { |a| a.products.posts}
```

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
@posts_in_my_clubs do |post|
```

Gives me the error:

> undefined method `memberships' for
>   nil:NilClass

To which I am not surprised.  Additionally I want to be able to select only the posts that will be only at a certain event, etc.

A summary of the models: Clubs have many Events & Users.  Users have many Products to which they can Post a quantity to sell at different Event dates.  Only Users who are members of a Club can post or view posts in a Club.

Instead of repeating data in the models, I have made associations, which seem to make the data inaccessible to creating collections in ActiveRecord.  I've found in my research [Association Join Models](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), and [Intelligent association mapping](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/#associations) with metawhere.  These links make me feel like I'm getting close.

Edit

I'm signed in and can access all of the data I need as long as I'm not trying to do a collection like this. For instance I can check if I'm a member of the club by

```
def member?(club) 
   return !!self.clubs.find(club)
```

I am a noob, so I must be missing something obvious here.  Do I need to break up my collection into steps?  i.e.  collect user clubs, collect user clubs products, collect user clubs products posts...  thanks

Logger.info

```
    @user = current_user
    logger.info @user 
    logger.info 'super secret message'
   # @club_posts = @user.memberships.collect {|a| a.product.posts}
```

returns

```
#<User:0x5b202a0>
super secret message
```

When I remove the comment, I get the nil error again, for 'product' now  (progress!).  I sure thought I was logged in before.. tho it was late

Comment: First solve problem with "NilClass" error, because you obviously don't have User returned by `current_user`. Does your controller properly authenticate user in before_fitler? If you require user, do you check if you have authenticated user in this action?

Comment: Read again my comment - your `@user` variable holds nil. There's not problem with your collections. It's problem with your authentication code. Put `logger.info @user` in index after you assign `@user = current_user`. If it outputs `nil`, then you don't have User record in `@user` variable, so it's not problem with collections and relationships yet.

Comment: Thanks, logging will help debug.

Comment: I'm making progress, but I still can't collect past the third level of heierarchy.  Here's my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262233/how-to-collect-through-multiple-sub-categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found, using gem nested_has_many_through, which is standard in Rails 3.1

## User model

```
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :product_posts, :through => :products, :source => :posts, :uniq => true
  has_many :food_orders, :through => :product_posts, :source => :orders, :uniq => true
```

## OrdersController

```
 @orders_for_my_products = current_user.food_orders.all
```

## Orders index

```
<%= render :partial => "order", :collection => @for_my_products, :locals => {:order => @order}  %>
```

This returns the deep nested data via relationships using minimal code.  I sure hope its efficient, but at least my sanity is spared!

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that `current_user` is `nil`. Are you sure your authentication system is working?

Comment: I'm signed in and can access all of the data I need as long as I'm not trying to do a collection like this.  For instance I can check if I'm a member of the club by def member?(club)
    return !!self.clubs.find(club)